# Resize Embedded video links HTML

Tags: html, css, video, width

I want my embedded videos to resize to the mobile width of the site, rather than extend beyond. This is my HTML code:

```
    <h2>Videos</h2>

    <section class="videos">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" 
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LCDLaQkAASU"
          frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" 
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S-OMryYGuhA"
          frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </section>
```

What must I put in my CSS code in order to do that?

Comment: Does changing the width and height attributes not work? By mobile width of the site you want it to be mobile responsive?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
.videos, .videos iframe {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are after the mobile width of the site (do you mean browser?), you can simply set width:100vw;

```
<iframe width="100vw"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LCDLaQkAASU"
          frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

vw sets the viewport width. By having it at 100 then the width of your iframe will be set the full width of the browser. If you want it to be mobile responsive i suggest you use @media queries to set the block off point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wrap class video in CSS:

```
.video {
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 100%;
}

.video iframe, .videos object, .video embed {
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

Put each video on it's own wrap like this

```
<section class="videos">
    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LCDLaQkAASU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S-OMryYGuhA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works perfectly EXCEPT now it only shows one embedded link. The top one has disappeared somewhere!

Comment: It's almost as if the videos are being overlapped one right on top of the other..

Comment: @Dima I edited my answer. Put each video on it's own wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS code:

```
   .video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.video iframe,
.video object,
.video embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```